Running wine results in error message "it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it."
Similar problem as here but not quite the same and also not on Ubuntu 23.04 but on 24.04 LTS.
When I try to run wine it results in this message:
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32:i386"

When trying to run sudo apt-get install wine32:i386 it results in:
sudo apt-get install wine32:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgd3:i386 : Depends: libheif1:i386 (>= 1.17.6-1ubuntu4~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

When trying to instal libheif1:i386 it results in:
sudo apt-get install libheif1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libheif1:i386 : Depends: libdav1d5:i386 (>= 0.1.0) but it is not installable
Depends: libde265-0:i386 (>= 1.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo apt update gives this output:
OK:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:2 https://ubuntu.mirror.wearetriple.com/archive noble InRelease
OK:3 http://packages.easyroam.de/repos/easyroam-desktop stable InRelease
OK:4 http://ftp.klid.dk/ftp/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:5 http://ubuntu.mirror.tudos.de/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:6 https://mirror.united-gameserver.de/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Holen:8 https://typora.io/linux ./ InRelease [793 B]
OK:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Holen:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
OK:12 http://ftp.tudelft.nl/archive.ubuntu.com noble InRelease
OK:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
OK:14 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
OK:16 http://nl3.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:17 https://nl.mirrors.clouvider.net/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:18 https://mirror.nl.mirhosting.net/ubuntu noble InRelease
Holen:19 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease [7.553 B]
Holen:20 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease [7.456 B]
Holen:15 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
OK:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
OK:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu noble InRelease
Holen:23 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease [7.450 B]
OK:9 https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu noble InRelease
OK:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Holen:25 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease [7.449 B]
OK:26 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Es wurden 413 kB in 3 s geholt (136 kB/s).
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Alle Pakete sind aktuell.

And the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-noble.sources are:
Types: deb
URIs: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
Suites: noble
Components: main
Architectures: amd64 i386
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key

The question now would be: Do I even need this wine32:i386 package or can I ignore it? And if I need it, how can I get it?

It may have helped if you had run the actual command it said and not an abbreviated version of it. Read the command again and cut and paste it into the terminal. Also the non English paste is of no help.

@DavidDE I did run the same command as you can see in the first row of the pasted text. Or do you mean apt-get instead of apt?

Can only go but what you put in the question and what you said you did and what it told you to do. do not match.

@DavidDE there you go, I edited the question. but the output still stays the same...

I found a hint to a solution here. It says: "The solution is to either change the installed version of the library back to the one from the standard repository so you can install both the 32 and 64 bit packages, or find an i386 package whose version exactly matches the one already installed."
Unfortunately I don't really understand what that means :(

Did you add some external repository when you tried to install wine? Please add the full output of sudo apt update to your question.

@OrganicMarble yes I installed it like they describe it here. Added the output to the question :)

I would expect your apt issues are due to the large number of ppas you've added to your system. If they only started when you tried to install wine, I personally would ppa-purge that wine repo, and install the version of wine from the ubuntu repos. If you know that you have a definite need for the latest version of wine, that won't work of course.

Okay so with the help of the comment by @Organic Marble I managed to get it to work!
I did sudo ppa-purge -s dl.winehq.org -o wine-builds -p ubuntu to purge the PPA and removed the manually created files in
/etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-noble.sources

As well as the ~/.wine directory.
But that was not the whole solution to the problem!
As stated here:

Starting with Ubuntu 24.04, a new configuration file, /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources, is used for managing repository configurations.

I still had my config in /etc/apt/sources.list since I upgraded from 22.04. So i removed the said file and created a new file/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources with these contents:
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports noble-proposed
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
Types: deb deb-src 
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


After that I simply ran sudo apt install --install-recommends wine and checked if the problematic wine32:i386 package was included in the installation candidates which it was!
Now everything works fine :)

Nice job, glad you got it sorted out.

Not sure how that worked for you. I am hitting the same error and wine won't install, neither wine32:i386 because the libdav1d5:i386 is simply missing. What repository has it?
